# How Best to Improve Concentration Saves (or avoid the check all together)?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, concentration

As I see it there are the following options:

**Character Build:**

- Take a level of a class with Con save proficiency at first level.
- Ability Increase (Con).
- Diamond Soul - (14th level Monk - not really viable)
- Aura of Protection - (+Paladin's Charisma bonus, Also affects nearby allies)
- Tides of Chaos - (Advantage, Wild Magic Sorcerer ability, self only)
- Bend Luck - (+1d4, Wild Magic Sorcerer ability used on another)
- Dark One's Own Luck - (+1d10, Fiend Pact Warlock, self only)
- Portent - (Replace a bad roll, Diviner ability)
- Transmuter's Stone - (Proficiency, Transmuter ability, but you have to give up other powers)
- Inspiration - (You must have Inspiration, game mechanic)
- Lucky - (Reroll bad rolls, feat)
- Lucky - (Reroll bad rolls, 1/2ling ability)
- Resilient - (Proficiency, feat)
- War Caster - (Advantage, feat)
- Focused Conjuration -  (Can't be broken, Conjuration spells only, Conjurer ability)
- Bardic Inspiration - (+1dx, Bard ability, thanks BlueMoon93)

**Spells:**

- Bless - (1d4 added to save, requires concentration... so defeats the purpose unless you can use it on more than one player.)
- Foresight - (advantage w/o concentration, but this is a 9th level spell)
- Gaseous Form - (advantage, requires concentration, can't cast spells - this is for skedaddlin')
- Holy Aura - (advantage, requires concentration - 8th level spell, and super costly)
- Shapechange - (Change into a creature with proficiency and even advantage with Con Saving throws - 9th level spell)

**Magic Items & Boons:**

- Belt Of Dwarvenkind, MANUAL OF BODILY HEALTH, Ioun Stone of Fortitude, Blessing of Health - (Increase Con by 2)
- Amulet of Health - (Con is set to 19)
- Holy Avenger, CANDLE OF INVOCATION - (Advantage - while in effect)
- Cloak of Protection, Luck Blade (also reroll), Stone of Good Luck, Ring of Protection, Robe of Stars, Rod of Alertness - (+1 bonus)
- Staff of Power - (+2 bonus)

**Other Options**

- Don't get hit!  - High AC, or non concentration spells that mess with
  getting hit (mage armor, mirror image, feats to wear armor, levels of Cleric/Fighter), Up your Dex
- Use Cover - Thanks BlueMoon93  & nitsua60
- Don't be seen - Invisibility, Illusions, get stealth skills.
- Get out of combat - Mist Step, Dimension Door
- Go Prone against Ranged attacks - thanks BlueMoon93 & nitsua60
- Warding Flare (Light Domain Cleric)
- Defensive Duelist feat (finesse weapon required)

**Controversial or Edge Cases**

- [Temp hit points](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/55609/is-a-concentration-check-required-when-temporary-hitpoints-absorb-all-the-damage?rq=1)
- Make potions for spells that require concentration.

Are there other options that I have missed?

There are not a lot of ways to get to the concentration saving throw buffed.  Which is to be expected in 5e, but I am tired of losing a spell first or second round, so I am trying to build up a list of tactics / ideas on how best to hold onto that 5th level spell I just cast.

Comment: If you're going to be adding into this post answers that people give (and thereby undercut those answers' validity), I don't see how this Q&A is going to work. I can't quite find the words for it, but something seems broken/strained here.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because I can't quite see how this Q&A is going to work, and I want to get other experienced eyes onto it.

Comment: Well I can certainly not add to the post, if that would help.  And go back and remove the stuff I added.

Comment: I don't know... "what are all the ways to do *X*?" just seems like it's not going to mesh well with the Stack's tools. See [this meta on list questions](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6442/23970) for some more thoughts on the subject.

Comment: Maybe part of the problem is that this post ^^ should actually be split in two: the question, and then *your* answer, which is the list you've already compiled? (Man, I just feel like I'm floundering in the dark on this one....)

Comment: This looks like a project to just make a big ol' list, not a question that presents a problem that challenges answers to compete to solve it best. All possible on-topic answers appear to be equally valid, making it not a good fit for a Stack.

Comment: This place can come across as very insular, esoteric and arcane.  It's very frustrating.  I don't feel like I am here to waste y'all's time, but that is the vibe I am picking up - not just with my posts.

Comment: @JWT I can feel you. Once you understand how it works and why you will undoubtly feel better about it. For now, just remember: tis is not a discussion forum, it is a questions and answers site, and we need you to be able to choose a correct answer. Plan your question accordingly and be ready to accept that some problems are just not solvable on this site (because they don't fit the format).

Comment: Unfortunately I agree - you don't have a *specific* character who's trying to get better saves, and thus the community could reasonably be expected to choose the best answer "in your situation, it's best to do these three things." Rather, you're compiling a list of all *possible* ways to improve/avoid saves - which, while mildly interesting, is a long list that will grow forever as new material is released. Hosting reference documents of that kind isn't really our thing. In the abstract, we can debate how much harm off-topic posts really do, but it's not what the format is designed for.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You forgot (at least) four! **Bardic Inspiration**:

> Once within the next 10 minutes, the creature can roll
>   the die and add the number rolled to one ability check,
>   attack roll, or saving throw it makes.

You can also complement the **Dont get seen/hit** sections!

- **Stealth**. **Hide** somewhere to avoid detection and be harder to target.
- If attackers are ranged, drop **Prone**. Ranged attacks against you have disadvantage. This is a big no-no against melee enemies, which get advantage. (thanks to nitsua60)
- Use **cover**. Run behind a wall, or inside a box, for full cover. Even standing just behind a brick fence gives you semi-cover and a buff to AC. (thanks to nitsua60)

Comment: I'll add those to the list.  The prone one is really good.  I have been pegged by a couple of giant propelled boulders of late, and it is no fun.