# Where is the compiled or most recent Errata found for PHB, DMG, and MM

Tags: dnd-5e

As I said before when I made this question. It is asking for a list of errata or a website where a list can be found. The other questions that were asked were marked answered with incomplete or outdated information. Please un-mark this as a duplicate. It is not.

This is not a duplicate of other questions which were answered over a year ago with out of date information.

I'm looking for the most recent errata for the PHB, DMG, and MM, or a compiled errata document, or a website that keeps up with the most recent errata with links.

( At the moment I specifically want to know if the monster creation chart in the DMG has been altered to reflect the method used to create creatures in the MM, but I figured that the better question would be where to find this info).

Comment: The thing to do imo is update the answers to those questions, not ask a new one

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where will errata be posted/published?](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/50890/where-will-errata-be-posted-published) And to tag onto @Wibbs's comment we do have a meta about [how to deal with wanting updated info on old questions](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/2960/whats-the-proper-way-to-ask-for-new-answers)

Comment: I've updated the previous question--it's got the correct link now to get all of the errata.